# Hide Content Type Default Pages from Search Results

Tags: 7, views, nodes, search

I have multiple content types where users enter data that I consume in views and create pages from.

I want to exclude some of these default content type rendered pages from the search results, but do not want to exclude the content and the views page where the results are.

For example, I have Basic Page Content Type and want to see any basic page content. I also have Custom Page Content Type and want to see these fields, but not the default rendered page, just my View created page that consumes the Custom Page Content Type fields.

Where do I set this up or how do I set up search to handle this type of need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Search module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search).

> This module alters the default search box in many ways. If you need to
>   have options available like in advanced search, but directly in the
>   search box, this module is for you. D8.x notes
>
> The module adds options to select:
>
> ```
> which content type(s) to search,
> which specific module search to use (node, help, user or any module that implements search),
> which input type to use (with Elements),
> advanced criteria
> ```
>
> For all these choices, there are options to switch between a select
>   box, checkboxes or radio buttons, and also customize the selector
>   label and the default - Any - text. Advanced options
>
> There are also options to:
>
> ```
> change the default search box label,
> add a default text in the search box,
> add advanced search criteria,
> change the default submit button text,
> use an image instead of the submit button,
> change the order of all the elements,
> include some elements in a popup block,
> add a filter to the results page,
> show/hide basic and/or advanced search in the results page,
> show/hide meta data in the results page,
> multiple search paths
> ```